# How to fix Gnome Desktop Environment crashing since updating to 19.10

Tags: gnome, xorg, crash, 19.10

Since updating to 19.10 I've been having a really bad user experience in the UI. I'm not sure if it's gnome or X but the main problem is that every now and then (~ once every 2 days) the DE will just crash and I lose all my sessions. I don't know if it's related to my other problem but when I open all my applications, the UI is very choppy, even moving a bluetooth mouse looks choppy. The UI is not responsive at all. If I close my IDE or Chrome, it becomes smoother so it must be related to resources. However, that never happened with 19.04 or 18.10

This is a part of my syslog after the GDM crash

```
Dec 10 12:53:34 developorium systemd-resolved[1236]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 100.70.133.50.
Dec 10 12:53:39 developorium systemd-resolved[1236]: Using degraded feature set (TCP) for DNS server 100.70.133.51.
Dec 10 12:53:39 developorium xdg-desktop-por[2874]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list:
 GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Dec 10 12:53:44 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: Object .Gjs_AppSwitcherPopup (0x56427e7393d0), has been already deallocated — impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs.
Dec 10 12:53:44 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: clutter_actor_destroy: assertion 'CLUTTER_IS_ACTOR (self)' failed
Dec 10 12:53:44 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: == Stack trace for context 0x56427bceb3e0 ==
Dec 10 12:53:44 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: #0   564282ece4d0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js:2097 (7fd94c83e8b0 @ 410)
Dec 10 12:53:44 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: #1   7ffedcd1f270 b   self-hosted:981 (7fd94c734160 @ 474)
Dec 10 12:54:39 developorium xdg-desktop-por[2874]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Dec 10 12:54:57 developorium systemd-resolved[1236]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 10 12:54:57 developorium systemd-resolved[1236]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 10 12:55:39 developorium xdg-desktop-por[2874]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Dec 10 12:57:39 developorium xdg-desktop-por[2874]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed]
Dec 10 12:58:16 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: Could not create selection source for X11: Format TARGETS not supported
Dec 10 12:58:39 developorium xdg-desktop-por[2874]: Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed
Dec 10 13:00:22 developorium kernel: [84489.503259] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp2s0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:58:23:8c:0d:bc:58:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 PROTO=2 
Dec 10 13:00:39 developorium xdg-desktop-por[2874]: message repeated 2 times: [ Failed to get application states: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.Failed: Could not get window list: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed]
Dec 10 13:00:51 developorium intellij-idea-community_intellij-idea-community.desktop[2939]: 2019-12-10 13:00:51,805 [7405133]   WARN - ntellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup - huge popup requested: 2797 x 26
Dec 10 13:00:51 developorium intellij-idea-community_intellij-idea-community.desktop[2939]: 2019-12-10 13:00:51,855 [7405183]   WARN - ntellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup - huge popup requested: 2797 x 26
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2726]: i965: Failed to submit batchbuffer: Bad address
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium gnome-terminal-[3485]: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium [12053]: org.gnome.gedit: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: [5895:5895:1210/130121.762059:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(62)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium gnome-shell[2939]: [5941:5941:1210/130121.762053:ERROR:x11_util.cc(110)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium [10768]: seahorse: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium [4034]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium [3095]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Dec 10 13:01:21 developorium pulseaudio[2711]: X connection to :0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).
```

I think the crash happened at around **13:00:51** since I was trying to see the content of a variable in IntelliJ and the warning about a huge popup coincides.

Does anyone know of this bug or how to fix it?

I have only 3 gnome extensions installed in my system, AFAIR all by default

```
$ ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Apr 27  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:23 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:23 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 24 12:25 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
```

This is my graphic card info

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128
        Memory at ee000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)
        Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
        Capabilities: [300] Page Request Interface (PRI)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

Comment: I breifly skimmed that article so please read it for accurate details....

Comment: You probably have a bad GNOME Shell extension... like maybe AppSwitcherPopup... edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /var/crash`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema thank you. unfortunately, i have no extensions `ls: cannot access '/home/hilikus/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory`  and `/var/crash` is empty. is that normal given that the GDM crashed yesterday?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff i don't understand. what does a release announcement have to do with my crashing problem?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`, and also go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and tell me what extensions you see there... should be 2 or 3 minimum. Also, what video card/driver do you have installed? Also show me `free -h`.

Comment: What version intellij? See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/ released two weeks ago.

Comment: @heynnema done. check the update. as for the extensions.gnome.org site, i don't have the required browser extension and would prefer not to add anything extra unless you think it will help with troubleshooting and not just a convenience that i would never use and would increase my attack vector. as for `free -h`, i just restarted my system but i usually use all RAM (8GB) and swap 50% used (5GB total). IntelliJ 2019.3

Comment: If you don't wish to install the two items required to view/manage your GNOME extensions... no big deal... however there's no harm/attack vector to do so. You only have the minimum 3 standard extensions now. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, and your make/model of computer/motherboard, and lets check your BIOS.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102080/discussion-between-hilikus-and-heynnema).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/users/172846/hilikus It doesn't..as I stated...Interesting.....